# Getting a value where another value is true

Tags: jquery, json

I'm trying to get a value from a JSON response, where another value in the response is true... Sounds messy, I'm new to this, sorry.
Maybe this will help, here's a part of my JSON response:

```
({"findlocationresult":{
"from":{
"location":[{
  "@x":"1460658",
  "@y":"6247996",
  "displayname":"Stockholm (Ronneby kn)",
  "type":"S",
  "locationid":7432356},

  {
  "@x":"1628182",
  "@y":"6580960",
  "bestmatch":"true",
  "displayname":"Stockholm Centralstation",
  "type":"S",
  "locationid":7400001}
```

I'm trying to get the `displayname` where `bestmatch` is set to true. Also, `bestmatch` only exists at one item(?) in the response.

Hope you get what I'm trying to do! Greatly appreciate help!

Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

say your object is data

```
 $.each(data.findlocationresult.from.location,function(i,v){
     if(v.bestmatch !== undefined and v.bestmatch == true){
       alert(v.displayname);
     }
 });
```

Comment: Excellent, thanks!
I modified it to:
$.each(data.from.location, function(i, item) {
         if(data.from.location[i].bestmatch == "true"){
          var from = data.from.location[i].displayname;
          $('#output').append('<li>'+from);
         }
        })

Comment: ya.. cool.. nice work... anyways thanks... glad that it helped... happy coding.. :)

Answer (score 0):

you can get by iterating all the elements of json object in jquery.

try this

```
$.each(data.findlocationresult.from.location, function(i, item) {
    if(data[i].bestmatch == "true")
    alert(data[i].displayname);
  ...............
   });​
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try doing this

```
var str = \\your json string
var json = JSON.stringify(eval("(" + str + ")"));
var fromJson =  json.findlocationresult.from.location;
var size = fromJson.length;
var displayname=""
for(i=0;i<size;i++){
  if(fromJson[i].bestmatch=="true"){
    displayname = fromJson[i].displayname;
    break;
  }
}
```

alert(displayname);